# How to replace /lib/modules in chroot?

Tags: drivers, chroot

I have mounted my system where my modules were accidentally deleted, ALL of them, all of the OLD ones, and the most recent ones 3.2.41. I have mounted my system and I'm `chroot` and I don't know what to do here. I found an answer on here saying to download the headers, which when I tried, it said they were already the newest version, and make a symbolic link to `/lib/modules/linux-headers-pkgname/build`, and it allowed me to create the link to `/lib/modules/linux-headers-3.2.41/` but no further.

If anyone could help me fix this, I'm already `chroot` with my correct system mounted along with `proc`, `sys`, and `/dev/pts`, at this point I just don't know what package to download and install, or how to place what I need back into `/lib/modules`. Should I remove this symlink as well? I have the 3.2.41 backed up on an external drive, can I just copy it back into the correct folder and have my modules back? I'm using Ubuntu 32-bit 12.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I booted into the live system, logged into a root shell, logged into root

```
$ sudo -i password
```

I mounted my filesystem:

```
# mount /dev/sda6
```

then I mounted sys, proc, dev, & dev/ptsL

```
# mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
# mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
# mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
# mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
```

then I chroot'd:

```
# chroot /mnt
```

after that I made sure that any modules I had moved over were removed, because I was finally able to copy my modules that were backed up on my external, **and** the modules from the live system into my filesystem, and they didn't completely work, all they did was fix the problem mounting my other filesystems and some USB acccess. So to do this I used:

```
# rm -r /lib/modules
```

then I made sure my internet connection was still good:

```
$ ping -c 5 google.com
```

then, after verifying that I could access the internet, I ran some updates because every few days updates come out, and my filesystem checked my kernel to see if I needed to update anything and I was able to re-install my modules this way. I ran:

```
# apt-get update  
# apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After all this, I used `ls` to check and see if my modules were back and indeed they were, in `/lib/modules`. I rebooted the computer, and everything worked perfectly.

*Thanks the wonderful person that helped me, over at [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2149797)*